# R-Language: Plot IC50 return IC50 and 95% Confidence values

Tags: r, statistics

Can anyone point me in the right direction for plotting IC50 curves in R?  My example dataset is below (N=2).  I would like to plot the average of each of value and then the standard deviation of the population for the 2 values.  Ultimately, I need the iC50 and 95% Confidence Interval as well.

Thanks!

[µM]
10
5
2.5
1.25
0.625
0.3125
0.15625
0

Result 1
100
95
75
50
25
10
5
0

Result 2
110
90
87
65
35
15
10
0

Comment: You might want [this library](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ic50/) (if there's one thing I've learnt, it's that there's a library for _everything_)

Comment: I looked into that library, however I did not find anything that it addressed all my concerns.  I may have to figure out how to perform the calculations w/o a package and just using basic stats.

Comment: A couple of questions - Are you looking to fit separate curves to each of your results, and since there are many types of dose-response curves whose formulae are driven by the biological mechanism, do you have an idea of the formula relating the dose and response?